# How to control :selected for collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Currently if you call `@team.user_ids` it returns `"1,3,7"` as opposed to `[1,3,7]`. I need it to be like that for other reasons, but it's breaking the front-end `collection_select`. I've tested and it works fine with an array, so now the only step left is to manually choose what items are selected considering I can't do it the Rails default way.

```
= f.collection_select :user_ids, @company.users, :id, :username,
  { :include_blank => true }, { :multiple => true, :class => "chzn-select" }
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `:selected => @team.users.map(&:id)`